# Unable to retrieve files from sub folders within sub folder recursively in SPO list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, folder, subfolders, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to display the versions of each item in a folder that contains sub folders.

Since I don't necessarily want to scan a whole SPO list, I specified to start in a certain folder, `e.g. '/Documents/test'`. If this starting folder contains a sub folder, e.g. '`/Documents/test/subtest`' I'm also able to retrieve it and its contents. However if this sub folder contains one more level my script doesn't retrieve it and its contents. I don't know what I can do to drill down recursively.

I appreciate any tips.

```
$site = "https://finnova-my.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso"  
$folderPath = "/Documents/test"

Connect-PnPOnline $site -Credentials $credential
$spoCred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials 
$credential.UserName, $credential.Password

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $site
$ctx.Credentials = $spoCred

$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


$serverRelativeUrl = (Get-PnPList Documents).RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl

$folder = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($site+$folderPath)
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.Load($folder.Folders)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

ForEach ($subFolder in $folder.Folders)
{
    $ctx.Load($subFolder.Files)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  ForEach ($file in $subFolder.Files)
  {
      $file.Name
      $version = $file.Versions
      $ctx.Load($version)
      $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
      $versionCount = $version.Count
      $versionCount
  }
}
```

Comment: Put your code in one function and call it recursively. Obvious you need bit modification in you code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried programming recursively?

You could also make a list of folders to "work on"...

```
WHILE there are items in the WORKLIST
  take the first item off the work-list and call it WORKITEM
  FOREACH sub-items in WORKITEM
    IF sub-item is a ListItem 
      process the versions
    ELSE //it mus be a folder....
      append sub-item to WORKLIST
```